# Is there a way to cast Class to IJavaElement

Tags: java, class

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to create a class and implements IJavaElement?

Comment: Cast an object of type `Class` to a `IJavaElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast any object of an arbitrary type to any other arbitrary class or interface type.

Casting (from one non-primitive type to another non-primitive type) does not do any magic automatic conversions. When you cast an object of type `A` to type `B`, what it means is that you tell the compiler "look, I have some object of type `A` here, and I want you to treat it as if it is a `B`; don't give me a type error, because I know better".

The type check will still be done, but at runtime instead of compile time. If, at runtime, the object turns out to not be a `B`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Assuming you're talking about class `java.lang.Class`, then no, you cannot cast that to `IJavaElement` (wherever that comes from) because `IJavaElement` is not a superclass of nor an interface implemented by `java.lang.Class`. If you try to do the cast, you'll get a `ClassCastException` when you run your program.

Comment: Thanks I believe so. IJavaElement comes from Eclipse JDT. But what if Class A implements Interface. Then you get A.getClass() instanceof Interface, this should work right?

Comment: Crap. A instanceof Interface will work but not A.getClass().